# How can I insert a specified tuple in a tuple list

Tags: python, insert, tuples

There is a tuple which looks like: 
Tuple a = [(0,20),(3,40),(9,55)..]
now I use a for loop to pull out each item from the tuple list,

```
for item1, item2 in (a):
    worksheet.write_number (row, col , float(item1))
    worksheet.write_number (row, col + 1, float(item2))
```

if i want to insert a tuple like (6,45) between (3,40) and (9,55)
,is there any function that I can used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert an item in a list at a specific point using:

```
list.insert(i,x)
```

Where i is the index of the item you want to insert BEFORE and x is the thing to insert.

So if you first find the index of the tuple that you want to insert a new tuple before ( (9,55) in your example at index i=2) , you can just do:

```
a.insert(i, (6,45))
```

More information can be found on the python list documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for insert try this,
you need 2 arguments **1) index 2) value**

```
>>> a =[(0,20),(3,40),(9,55)]
>>> a.insert(2,(6,45)) # here 2 is index where to insert and (6,45) is value
>>> a
[(0, 20), (3, 40), (6, 45), (9, 55)]
>>>
```